# Nginx location $request_filename not set right with rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

When I write the location in, it works, when I use the same location as a rewrite rule, it doesnt!!! I dont understand the logic. Can someone please explain?

```
   location /v3/ {
            alias /var/www/api/v3/html/;
            echo $document_uri;
            echo $document_root;
            echo $request_filename;
            echo $request_uri;
            echo $fastcgi_script_name;
   }
```

When I do the above, I get

```
/v3/info.php
/var/www/api/v3/html/
/var/www/api/v3/html/info.php
/v3/info.php
/v3/info.php
```

But if I now change the location to use rewrite:

```
   location ~ ^/(v\d+)/ {
            alias /var/www/api/$1/html/;
            echo $document_uri;
            echo $document_root;
            echo $request_filename;
            echo $request_uri;
            echo $fastcgi_script_name;
   }
```

The paths all get screwed:

```
/v3/info.php
/var/www/api/v3/html/
/var/www/api/v3/html/
/v3/info.php
/v3/info.php
```

How come??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [nginx ticket #657](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/657):

> That's expected behaviour. In a location defined by a regular
>   expression alias defines full path, so you have to use:

```
location ~ ^/(v\d+)/(.*) {
    alias /var/www/api/$1/html/$2;
    return 200 "request_filename: $request_filename";
}
```

Comment: I've come across so many other differences since then that I've learnt to work with it than how i would expect it to work :)

Comment: Ticket opened... and closed: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/657 I edited my answer to reflect nginx team's